# How to display sections in NSIS without letting the user choose a section

Tags: installation, nsis

I have written an NSIS installer with three install sections like shown in this example (this is not my installer, but mine looks nearly the same):

[Example for section screen](http://i444.photobucket.com/albums/qq170/MikeWard88/private/setupfile.jpg)

But here the user has the chance to select some section, but this I want to avoid.
Of course I know that sections are especially made for this but I just want to show the user what kind of parts my application has, but he should not be able to select/deselect something.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can..

1. force a section to be selected at all times using [SectionIn RO](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/SectionIn)
2. allow at least one section to be selected (see `NSIS\Examples\one-section.nsi`)